# How can I use this math mode pictogram (tree + leaf)?

Tags: symbols

In an article, I saw an equation with a pictogram where one might typically find a Latin letter:

[image: Branch and leaf as a symbol in an equation]

How did they do it? How can I replicate this equation in my own document?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/9517

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As addition to A.Elletts perfect answer:

If you want to use other symbols in order not copy the one from your PDF, you may get some inspiration here. There are many symbols included in the [Unicode 6.0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/version/6.0/index.htm).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\def\faTree{\FA\symbol{"F1BB}}

\begin{document}
    \faLeaf
    \faTree % not yet part of the package
    \setmainfont{symbola.ttf}
    \symbol{"1F331}
    \symbol{"1F332}
    \symbol{"1F333}
    \symbol{"1F334}
    \symbol{"1F335}

    \symbol{"1F33F}
    \symbol{"1F341}
    \symbol{"1F342}
    \symbol{"1F343}
    \symbol{"1F384}
    \symbol{"2E19}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
% arara: lualatex 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\twig}{\reflectbox{\rotatebox{35}{\setmainfont{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F33F}}}}
\newcommand*{\leaf}{\ensuremath{\text{\faLeaf}}}

\begin{document}
In the following formula I will use a \twig{} and a \leaf{} combined to $\twig^\leaf$: 
\[
\mbfitY=f(\mbfitX)+\mbfscrE\approx\twig^\leaf_1(\mbfitX)+\twig^\leaf_2(\mbfitX)+\ldots+\twig^\leaf_m(\mbfitX)+\mbfscrE,\quad\mbfscrE\sim\mscrN_n(\mathbf{0}, \sigma^2 \mbfitI_n)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I actually don't like their particular choice of symbol because I feel they're too "chunky" and "round" and break up the flow of the equation. However I really like the idea of using symbols aside from the Greek/Latin alphabets, so a general solution is even better. I could also probably mess around with font sizes and macros to make these less conspicuous.

Answer (score 8):

The one symbol can be found in the package `textcomp` as `\textleaf`.  In your preamble, just enter

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

and in the body of the document write `\textleaf`.

The other symbol can be found in the package `phaistos` as `\PHplaneTree`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{phaistos}
\newcommand\myleaf{\mbox{\textleaf}}
\newcommand\mytree{\mbox{\PHplaneTree}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$\mytree^{\myleaf}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I found that I had to put the two objects in their own boxes to get these symbols to work in math mode.

From the command line you can type

```
texdoc symbols-a4
```

to get a master document showing a variety of different symbols and the packages which provide them.